# How to disable comments in WordPress blog for non admin users?

Tags: wordpress

In my WordPress website I'm allowing comment section under all articles. The requirement is to allow only for logged in users. If a user is viewing the article without logging in, Now it asks his name and email along with the comments. And it immediately reflects in the comment section. What I want is any one option from below.

1. Logged out user can comment. But it will be reflect only if admin accepts.
2. Logged out user doesn't have comment section.

How to achieve anyone requirement?

Comment: Try filter mentioned here with some logic like if user is not logged in then or whatever logic that you would like to implement. http://www.geekerhub.com/disable-wordpress-comments-flood-prevention/

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to implement are defaults, already built-in, Wordpress behaviours.

You can either manually set that under `settings` > `discussion` and `settings` > `general` or implement the following function in your `function.php`.

Either use [`init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) or [`after_switch_theme`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_switch_theme/) as action hook.

```
<?php
/**
* Define default theme options.
* @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference
*/
add_action( 'init', function() {

  /**
  * comment_moderation
  * Before a comment appears, an administrator must always approve the comment.
  * @param  Integer
  */
  update_option( 'comment_moderation', 1  ); // ... default: 0

  /**
  * comment_registration
  * Users must be registered and logged in to comment
  * @param  Integer
  */
  update_option( 'comment_registration', 1  ); // ... default: 0
} ); ?>
```